# Including a maven artifact in Dockerfile

Tags: maven, docker

We have a requirement to include a maven artifact (a jar file) in a Dockerfile. This jar file is used an as argument in the run command of our application. What is the correct way of copying a maven artifact in the Dockerfile which does not exist in the build directory and only exists in the local maven repo? I have found that since maven artifacts wont be in the build context, the only way to copy it is from the .m2 directory of the container (.m2 directory contains all the maven artifacts). Is that correct or is there a better way?
Thanks

Comment: After a build of a project the resulting artifacts are in `target` directory available...in `$HOME/.m2/repository` they are only if you do `mvn install`...

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by copying the jar to your image when creating it.

here's an example. Assuming you wanna using the Quava jar, and it is already listed as a dependency in your POM.

Create `Makefile` in your root project (where you have your POM.xml),

```
create_image: Dockerfile build
        docker build . -t myimage:mytag

build: POM.xml
        mvn clean install
```

Create Dockerfile in the same directory:

```
FROM centos
COPY ~/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/14.0.1/guava.jar /
CMD ["sh run.sh", "/quava.jar']
```

and simply create your image using:

`make create_image`